# User duplicates answers

Tags: discussion

I posted an answer to this question [Is there a way to redirect to another page in php without using header()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033541/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-to-another-page-in-php-without-using-header) and a few minutes later, I see another answer which is an exact copy+paste of my answer and the one before, compiled into 1 answer, posted by this user https://stackoverflow.com/users/4189838/levent-tulun

I went through his answer history, and all of his answers are straight copy/paste (minus some formatting issues) of previous answers.

What would be the best course of action against the user or individual answer posts? - I realise there is no specific rule against posting /similar/ (duplicate) answers, but it adds low quality content to Stack Overflow.

Considering every post he's made is a duplicate of other answers, should we mark all of his answers for moderators attention, or is there another course of action? Should I just ignore it?

**Edit:** Issue has been resolved, and user temporarily banned. Thanks moderators for swift action.

Comment: C'mon, man, he gives out hugs *"because i am HM, i hug you Salman A"*

Comment: An other user already posted about this a few seconds before your post was ready. I closed as dupe...